# How to find the positive difference between two DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I've two DateTime variable regardless of which is greater than the other in time.

```
Datetime date1, date2;
```

How should I find the positive difference of both on "days" basis?

`(date1-date2)` might give positive/negative result but I also need the no: of days difference.

Assume both are on the same TimeZone

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
double days = Math.Abs((date1-date2).TotalDays);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want an (unsigned) integer value:

```
Math.Abs(date1.Subtract(date2).Days)
```

If you want an (unsigned) double value:

```
Math.Abs(date1.Subtract(date2).TotalDays)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [Days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) property on the timespan (which is the resulting type from `date1 - date2`). It returns a signed int.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Math.Abs((dateA - dateB).Days);
```

or if you want the result to be fractional:

```
Math.Abs((dateA - dateB).TotalDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the subtraction operator with the `TimeSpan.Duration()` method.

This method returns the **absolute value** of the current `TimeSpan` object.

Sample code:

```
    public static int GetDayDifference(DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2)
    {
        TimeSpan diff = (dateTime1 - dateTime2).Duration();
        return diff.Days;
    }
```

Lets test it: Using these DateTime variables,

```
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 3);
```

Now both of the following lines will give the same result (2 days):

```
GetDayDifference(dateTime1, dateTime2));
GetDayDifference(dateTime2, dateTime1));
```